# data-synchronization problem in batch script when querying register data, I need something like RegFlushKey but in batch

Tags: function, batch-file, registry, data-synchronization

I'm querying register values as part of unit testing for a batch script that will set up a network for our customers. I've identified a race condition wherein querying a register after setting it to a value in the same function causes the old value to appear untill you re-run the batch file. An example in my block of code is as follows:

```
:MyFunctionName
REM some initialization code

powercfg /change monitor-timeout-ac 2 1> nul 
powercfg /change standby-timeout-ac 2 1> nul 
powercfg /change hibernate-timeout-ac 2 1> nul

REM code that gets register paths setup and does some other irrelevant stuff
REM MonitorTimeoutPath is the path to the first powercfg setting
REM StandbyTimeoutPath is the path to the second setting
REM HibernateTimeoutPath is the path to the third setting

FOR /F "tokens=1-3 skip=2" %%A IN ('reg query "!MonitorTimeoutPath!" /v ACSettingIndex') DO (set /A "ActualMonitorTimeout=%%C/60")
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 skip=2" %%A IN ('reg query "!StandbyTimeoutPath!" /v ACSettingIndex') DO (set /A "ActualStandbyTimeout=%%C/60")
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 skip=2" %%A IN ('reg query "!HibernateTimeoutPath!" /v ACSettingIndex') DO (set /A "ActualHibernateTimeout=%%C/60")

REM code that tests values but is important for now

echo M:!ActualMonitorTimeout! S:!ActualStandbyTimeout! H:!ActualHibernateTimeout!
goto:EOF
```

Now here is the important thing, when I set the three powercfg settings to different values (say 1,1,2 respectively) the FIRST time I run the batch file, the echo statement shows me values of 0,0,0 and only when I run the file a SECOND time do I see the true values of 1,1,2. Since I'm 99.99% sure I'm not accessing it wrong because I use VERY similar FOR statements to grab register data when I do it outside of the same function like this:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\StickyKeys" /v Flags /t REG_SZ /d 10 /f 1> nul 
call :RegTestFunc "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\StickyKeys" Flags 10

:RegTestFunc
REM some code
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 skip=2" %%A IN ('reg query "%~1" /v %~2 2^>nul') DO (set /A "RegisterData=%%C")
REM some more code
goto:EOF
```

So there is virtually no difference except some math differences (hence why I couldn't use the function) and some syntax (because its a function). The point is, my syntax seems to be fine here and it doesn't cause race conditions when I use the `RegTestFunc`. It only happens when I directly run the querying operation in the same function that I set the register value.

To try to solve this I tried researching what (if any) form of timing control batch had and I came across the timeout command. I used it, thinking I could delay the processor so the register value would be done changing by the time it was queried. Specifically I put it before the 3 `FOR` statements that query the data from the register. This didn't work hence why I'm asking here because Google is a useless search engine for anything interesting. Is there an easy way to make some sort of lock on the querying operation or its results so I always get the most recent changes? I'm pretty sure that cmd is just going so fast that the powercfg /change command can't get it's job done before the reg query command comes along and asks for outdated data. If need be I could just make another function and call it and see if that changes things but thats messy so I'd like to avoid that.

For reference: What would be the technical term for this problem? I don't see it as a race condition because there aren't multiple threads vying for the same register data, it isn't a consumer producer problem because the data is there, it just isn't being recognized. However, those concepts are very similar to whats actually happening (at least for me) so what would this "problem" be called? The data is changing/being queryed too fast but what would that formally be called (if anything)? My first thought was race condition, then consumer-producer, then stale data then I decided that synchronization problem would be the best words I would use to describe what I think is happening.

## UPDATE

I've tried changing all the important delayed expansion (!) variables in my code to non delayed (%) thinking that maybe it was grabbing old values via expansion and scope but this didn't work, the registers were still outdated by one run of the script. I also tried querying the registers twice and using a helper function to seperate the code and see if that worked but still it didn't work. My only guess is that changes to powercfg aren't finalized until the last statement of the batch script is reached so then my question is, how do I query accurate data before then?

## UPDATE 2

I've tried exporting the register data right after I set it.

```
REM RUNNING THE FILE THE FIRST TIME ASSUMING THE VALUES WERE ALL 0 BEFORE
powercfg /change monitor-timeout-ac 3 1> nul 
powercfg /change standby-timeout-ac 3 1> nul 
powercfg /change hibernate-timeout-ac 3 1> nul

REM some code
REM the below isn't runnable but the idea is that it contains the path to 
REM powercfg /change monitor-timeout-ac
reg export %MonitorTimeoutPath% foo.reg
```

(in foo.reg)

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Power\User\PowerSchemes\f4e62c59-ee57-456a-94c4-3662e9d6ceb9\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\3c0bc021-c8a8-4e07-a973-6b14cbcb2b7e]
>   "ACSettingIndex"=dword:00000000

Notice the hex value of 00 at the end (0 seconds or 0 minutes)

Then if you run the above script EVEN without the lines:

```
REM RUNNING THE FILE THE SECOND TIME
powercfg /change monitor-timeout-ac 3 1> nul 
powercfg /change standby-timeout-ac 3 1> nul 
powercfg /change hibernate-timeout-ac 3 1> nul
```

You get the correct value

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Power\User\PowerSchemes\f4e62c59-ee57-456a-94c4-3662e9d6ceb9\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\3c0bc021-c8a8-4e07-a973-6b14cbcb2b7e]
>   "ACSettingIndex"=dword:000000B4

(hex 180 seconds or 3 minutes)

And only after running the batch file twice does the actual value update EVEN IF I comment out the powercfg write lines on the second run so that the write to the registry happens only once. What this means is that the registry itself hasn't gotten the data yet when we query right after we change powercfg settings. I've researched the issue and what I need is an implementation of

```
RegFlushKey(hkey key);
```

Which apparently is something that exists in C and forces an update to the registry of the specified key (it writes that registry to 'the disk' immediately and halts everything else thus being slow). All that is detailed much better here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regflushkey and I need a way to do basically that in batch.

Answer (score 0):

## The issue

I found out what was wrong. I was querying a `DuplicateScheme` rather than the `ActiveScheme`.

When we were developing this script we had to include functionality for changing power settings on Windows 10 pro. You can't normally set the active scheme to the default GUID for high performance right off the bat because windows 10 pro is weird. Instead you have to use `DuplicateScheme` on the high performance guid so you can generate a new guid with the same settings. That same line of code also sets it as the `ActiveScheme` (that term will be important).

When the script was in development originally it was intended to also work with Windows 2016 server version (and some other versions as well). These versions didn't require the `DuplicateScheme` technique and instead you had to set the `ActiveScheme` to high powered directly. Trying to use the `DuplicateScheme` method on windows 2016 versions **shouldn't and didn't** work as expected.

My mistake was that even though I ran the `DuplicateScheme` method on Windows 2016 Server version, I thought it wouldn't affect anything else. I was wrong. Since the `DuplicateScheme` technique doesn't work on Windows 2016 Server verison, the PowerScheme Guid I was querying was never actually set to the `ActiveScheme`. I had an error check in place to find this error because I **expected** it to happen (and it did which is good). However, Since I was querying the results of `Powercfg` changes, I was trying to query my `DuplicateScheme` for changes that were made on the `ActiveScheme`. Since the changes were first made on the `ActiveScheme`, I didn't see them on the `DuplicateScheme` in time.

The standard behavior seems to be as follows:

1. running `Powercfg` commands that update registers for the `ActiveScheme` take affect immediately and can be queried without flushing them as I thought was needed
2. running `Powercfg` commands that update registers for Duplicates of the ActiveScheme (i.e. our `DuplicateScheme`) take effect after the batch file is done executing. Waiting for them to update with timeouts, pauses or some other means does not work. My Hypothesis is that DuplicateSchemes take on the changes of their parents after the batch file has concluded. My confusion was because I didn't recognize this behavior, I thought I was always editing the `ActiveScheme` but I was wrong.

## Code example of problem:

```
REM setting the ActiveScheme as per win10 spec
REM this creates the DuplicateScheme but only in windows 10 pro does it set this new 
REM scheme as the ActiveScheme also. In my version it did NOT do this
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('powercfg /duplicatescheme 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c') DO (SET PowerScheme=%%F)

REM some code to process things

REM code to modify the ActiveScheme
powercfg /change monitor-timeout-ac 1 1> nul 

REM some code to create MonitorTimeoutPath and other things

REM code to query the DuplicateScheme
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 skip=2" %%A IN ('reg query "%MonitorTimeoutPath%" /v ACSettingIndex') DO (set /A "ActualMonitorTimeout=%%C/60" & echo C:%%C)

REM IF we assume that we had ran 
REM [powercfg /change monitor-timeout-ac 0 1> nul]
REM previously, then running the above code results in output of:
C: 0

REM when whats expected is:
C: 1
```

The solution is to change `%MonitorTimeoutPath%` to the oath of the `ActiveScheme` not the `DuplicateScheme`.

So it turns out the actual problem was **completely unrelated** to flushing the register and I didn't need to go down that rabbit hole at all. Thanks brain. I accidentally discovered the solution by querying the `ActiveScheme` directly by key path rather than using the `%MonitorTimeoutPath%` which held the `DuplicateScheme` path.

## Tl;dr

The problem was I was updating an `ActiveScheme` and querying a `DuplicateScheme` and that should only work as I expected in Windows 10 Pro NOT Windows 2016 Server version (which I was running)